# Chrome hide menu items with background img

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, background-image

I have a menu with a background img in hover.
Only with crhome, i dont see the menu voices when I load the page.

Following, if I go with the mouse to select the voice, appears the menu voices with the img's background, and remains.

I dont have this problem with firefox.

That's the CSS code:

```
    #header {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    margin: auto ;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 130%;
    z-index: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;

    }
    #header .main_menu {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 700px;
    padding-top:  7.5px;
    z-index:100;

    }
    #header .main_menu  .normal {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    height: 14px;
    border: 2px solid white;  



    }
    .main_menu .logo_main_menu{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 140px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 14px 0px;
    height: 11.5px;
    border: 2px solid white;  

    }
    .main_menu .logo_main_menu:hover ,#header .here_home {
    color: transparent;
    background: url("../images/logo_tapling.png") ;
    background-size: 140px;

   }
    .normal:hover , #header .active{
    background: url("../images/bg_tapling.png") ;
    color: white;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px black  ;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px black  ;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px black ;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px black ;
    }
    .free_img_2{
    display: none;position: relative;height: 100px;margin-bottom: -100px;
    float: right;right: 146px;z-index: 20;
    }
    .free_img{
    position: relative; height: 100px;margin-bottom: -100px;
    float: right;top:-5px;right: -8px;
    }
    #header .main_menu .normal a:hover  {



    }

    .can_bg{
    border: 2px white solid;
    }

    #header .normal .active ,#header .normal .main_menu a:hover
    {





    }
    #mainmenu2{
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    /*top:60px;*/
    /*left:50%;*/
    /*margin-left: -235px;*/
    /*right: auto;*/ 
    /*margin:62px auto ;*/
    }
    #mainmenu2{
    display: none;
    border-left:2px solid white;
    border-right: 2px solid white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 8px 6px -3px  black ;
    -ms-box-shadow: 2px 8px 6px -3px  black ;
    -webkit-box-shadow:2px 8px 6px -3px   black;
    box-shadow: 2px 8px 6px -3px   black;
    border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    color:black;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:900;
    background: url("../images/bg_tapling.png") ;

    }
    #mainmenu2 ul{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
    #mainmenu2 li a{
    color: white;
    text-shadow: none;
    }
    #mainmenu2 li a:hover{
    color: green;
    }
    #mainmenu2 li .active{
    color: lightgreen;
    }
    #mainmenu2 li{
    width: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2.5px auto ;
    padding: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px black;
    -ms-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px black;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, 

    #ededed),color-stop(1, #000000) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #000000 100% );
    background:-ms-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #000000 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed',  

    endColorstr='#000000');
    background-color:black;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    -ms-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    /*border:1px solid #dcdcdc;*/
    display:inline-block;
    color:#777777;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    /*padding-right: 2.5%;*/
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
    }
    #mainmenu2 li:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, 

    #dfdfdf),      color-stop(1, #ededed) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100% );
    background:-ms-linear-gradient( center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfdfdf',   

    endColorstr='#ededed');
    background-color:#dfdfdf;
    }
    .logo {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px auto;
    height: 100%;
    }
    .logo img {
    height: 56px;

    }
    #header .menu {
    width: 434px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .menu{
    display: none;
    }
```

And this is HTML:

```
 <div id="header"> 
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="<?=URL?>" >
                    <img src="<?php echo URL; ?>theme/<?= $this->_theme ?    >/images/logo_tapling.png" />
                    </a>
                    <div class="separatore"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-responsive-menu">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="main_menu">

                <a href="<?=URL?>classifica" class="normal <?=$classifica?>    ">Classifica
                </a>

                <a href="<?=URL?>regole" class="normal <?=$regole?>">
                    Regole
                </a>

                <a href="<?=URL?>" class="logo_main_menu <?=$home?> "  >
                    Tapling
                </a>


                <a href="<?=URL?>faq" class="normal  <?=$faq?> ">Faq</a>


                <a href="<?=URL?>contatti" class="normal <?=$contatti?> ">Contatti</a>


            </div>

        </div>
```

Tnx so much!

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
 .normal:hover , #header .active{
        background: url("../images/bg_tapling.png") ;
        color: white;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px black  ;
        -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px black  ;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px black ;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px black ;
        }
```

to this

```
.normal:hover , #header .active{
            background: url("../images/bg_tapling.png") ;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px black  ;
            -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px black  ;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px black ;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px black ;
            }
```